# mongodb/iOS: Network connection lost on query with 5000 items

Tags: ios, objective-c, mongodb

- I have a mongodb running with **`default`** configuration on an EC2 instance.
- My collection only has 10 objects/documents.
- As a test, I send a `$in` query with 5000 elements where each element is a string of 15 characters.
- Total size of query is 65K

When I do the query I get an error `"Network connection was lost"`

I made the query from an iOS simulator.

is there any limit on such query? Can I change any configuration to solve this issue?

It does work when I change the query to send 2000/3000 elements

Comment: you probably want to re-work how you query - this is not a scalable approach.

Comment: yeah...I was just testing

Comment: How are you connecting to mongo via iOS? Are you connecting via some intermediate backend language such as Python/Ruby, or are you connecting directly from iOS to Mongo? If direct, what driver are you using?

Comment: ios direct...    NSURLSessionDataTask* dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {...} [dataTask resume];

Answer (score 0):

> Total size of query is 65K

Max query size is 16MB in MongoDB, so your query looks OK.

> It does work when I change the query to send 2000/3000 elements

This is almost 100% related to a connection timeout imposed by NSURLSessionDataTask.

> Can I change any configuration to solve this issue?

Try increasing your timeout like so:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30.0;
sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60.0;
```

I have to warn that increasing a timeout for any solution is an indicator that cracks are beginning to show, and that alternate approaches should be considered.

Comment: I understand...I have split my request to batches with each batch containing 500 elements (10 batches for testing)....but I dont know what is the right batch size....thats what I am trying to find out....I am not sure whether I should batch in 10, 100, 500 or 1000 elements

Comment: I think there must be an even better way. What is special about the 5000 elements you are checking against.

Comment: 5000 is just a number....in my test case I am assuming user has 5000 contacts in his address book for example...It could be 100 or 10000

Comment: What are the elements? Mongo object ids?

Comment: no its emailAddress where emailaddress is an index in mongo collection